# Charge particle moving in circular path between two charged concentric spheres

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

This is a question from a past exam paper that I'm using for practice. 
I've linked the pdf, it's question 2a
http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/sbs/registry/Exams/PastPapers/downloads/physics/2016/PHYS%20320.pdf

Question:
A particle of charge q and mass m moves in a circular path of radius r between two concentric spheres that are separated by a distance d such that $ d << r $. There is an electric potential difference between the spheres, V. For the particle to remain in a circular path and not collide with either sphere, the potential difference must be proportional to the energy of the particle and inversely proportional to the charge.
By equating the electrostatic force on the particle with the centripetal acceleration, derive an expression for V as a function of d, r, q and E where E is the particle kinetic energy.

Attempt:
I'm denoting the inner sphere to have radius of $R_1$ and charge $Q_1$. The outer sphere to have charge $Q_2$ and radius $R_2$.

Using Gauss' law I have an equation for the acceleration on a charge between the spheres
$F = ma = E q  \rightarrow a = \frac{Q_1 q}{4 \pi r^2 \epsilon_0 m} \hat{r}$.

I've calculated the potential difference to be $V = \frac{Q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left( \frac{1}{R_2} - \frac{1}{R_1} \right) $.

If kinetic energy is given by $E_k = \frac{m v^2 }{2} $ and centripetal acceleration is $a = \frac{ v^2}{r}$ we can equate these and rearrange to get;

$\frac{q}{r} \frac{ Q_1}{ 4 \pi \epsilon_0} = v^2 = 2\frac{E}{m}$

We can sub in our formula for V and rearrange to give

$V = \frac{2 r E }{q} \left(\frac{R_1 - R_2}{R_1 R_2} \right) = \frac{2 r d E }{q R_1 R_2} $

Issue:
I'm a bit stuck at this point, I need to sub out both R values and I see no good way of doing this. I was wondering if it's a fair assumption to set $R_1$ ~ $ R_2$ ~ $r $ due to the d>>r statement. If this is not possible then I feel like I may have made a mistake getting to this point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep these two things in mind:

- Since the charge $q$ is in a bound orbit and if $Q_1$ is positive, then $q$ is negative.
- In the total energy for $q$ don't forget to add the potential energy
  due to the outer shell $Q_2$.

Then just find $\frac{qV}{E}$. If this comes out to be a constant in terms of $Q_1,R_1, Q_2, R_2, d, r$  and independent of $q$ then you've proved that potential difference is proportional to the energy of the particle and inversely proportional to the charge.

Comment: Gauss' law says that only the enclosed charge is relevant to the electric field, does that not hold through for the potential as well? That would lead me to expect $ Q_2$ to not be in the result. The final formula I have does give $\frac{qV}{E} = \frac{2 r d}{R_1 R_2} $ which satisfies the proportionality conditions. However, the question says that V must be given in terms of d, r, q and E.
Edit: I've just realised I didn't copy in the final line of the question stating that last part,  apologies.